# Marketing cloud connector issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have installed Marketing cloud connector in Salesforce Sandbox. When i click on the 'marketing cloud' tab in Salesforce, I am getting error(see the screenshot). Anyone knows what would cause this? I tried uninstalling and installing it again but no luck.

> $Label.et4ae5.mCCSetup could not be retrieved from custom labels: You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Wile creating the Salesforce system user Make sure you have below settings

User License: Salesforce
Profile: System Admin

Checked the Marketing Cloud for AppExchange User Field.
Checked the Marketing Cloud for AppExchange Admin Field.

It seems more to be a permission issue than a connector issue.